# Forking in GitHub - Mainline Commits

Tags: git, github

In Github, when a fork a repo all the content's get copied to a new fork repo. I want to know if a commit happens in the original repo then can I also have that happen in the fork. If so how can I do so?

Also is it possible to change the name of the fork?

Comment: `can I also have that happen in the fork` ... can you pull from the main repo to the fork?

Comment: what do you mean? please elaborate.

Comment: I mean just manually check for any new commits.  In any case, should a merge conflict occur you would likely have to handle those manually anyway.

Comment: How can I check and add those commits? Thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the `original/repo`. Then create a `new/repo` (with the downloaded file) in your personal account with a `different name` as you want. Then go to `new/repo`.

```
$ git remote add upstream <original/repo/url>
$ git fetch upstream

$ git diff HEAD..upstream/master       # compare between HEAD and origin-repo-master if any change occurs 

# you can also pull original-repo-master-branch in another branch here and see the commit lists
$ git checkout -b <test-branch>
$ git pull upstream master            # pull upstream(original repo) master into local `test-branch`

$ git log                             # see the commit lists 

# You can take an original-repo-commit by `cherry-pick` manually. Copy the `commit-hash` from `git log`

$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick <commit-sha>        # take the original-repo-commit manually
```